# Is there any way to convert columns's value from nonconsecutive numbers to 1-started consecutive numbers?

Tags: pandas

For example,there is a pandax.DataFrame like this:

```
          col_1     col_2
idx_1     493       47
idx_2     229       46435
idx_3     998       56
idx_4     209       45
idx_3     998       56
```

and I want to find a easy to convert it to

```
          col_1     col_2
idx_1     3         2
idx_2     2         4
idx_3     4         3
idx_4     1         1
idx_3     4         3
```

As you can see,in each column,always convert smallest value to 1,then second smallest to 2,so on and so fourth,any easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df.rank(method="dense")
Out[8]: 
       col_1  col_2
idx_1    3.0    2.0
idx_2    2.0    4.0
idx_3    4.0    3.0
idx_4    1.0    1.0
idx_3    4.0    3.0
```

As the original values are of type float, the ranks are also floats. You can call `astype(int)` if you want:

```
df.rank(method="dense").astype(int)
Out[9]: 
       col_1  col_2
idx_1      3      2
idx_2      2      4
idx_3      4      3
idx_4      1      1
idx_3      4      3
```